# How to make display:none to the button for specific text?

Tags: reactjs

I want to hide the button for certain para. But it displays the button for all para.
There are two files.Please help me out to display the button for the only 1 para which is displayed in index.jsx

This is NotificationPreview.jsx which has the notification preview which should include button for only one para

```
import React ,{ useState }from 'react'
import { StyledNotificationPreview } from '.'
import { Avatar } from '../../System'
import styled from "styled-components";

const theme = {
  orange: {
    default: "#dfaf68",
    hover: "#e78e18"
  },
  red:{
    default:"red",
    hover:"red"
  }
};
const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(props) => theme[props.theme].default};
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px lightgray;
  transition: ease background-color 250ms;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => theme[props.theme].hover};
  }
  &:disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
`;
Button.defaultProps = {
  theme: "orange"
};

const Button1 = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(props) => theme[props.theme].default};
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px lightgray;
  transition: ease background-color 250ms;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => theme[props.theme].hover};
  }
  &:disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
`;
Button1.defaultProps = {
  theme: "red"
};

function clickMe(){
  alert("Clicked")
}



const NotificationPreview = ({img,name,para,time,avatar,stream,accept,decline}) => {
  const B = (props) => <span style={{fontWeight: '600'}}>{props.children}</span>
  const isBuzzedIn = true;

    return (
    
        <StyledNotificationPreview>
 <div className="container">
              {/* <img className="img1" src={img} style={{width:'6%'}} /> */}
              <div className="avatar">
                <Avatar size={40} url={avatar} alt="Profile picture" />
            </div>
              <div className="previewTextContainer">
            <span className="paragraphText"><B>{name} </B></span>
            <span className="paragraphText">{para}</span>
            <span className="paragraphText"><B>{stream}</B></span>
            <div className="btn"> 
        <Button onClick={clickMe}>{accept}</Button>
        {isBuzzedIn && <Button style={{display:"none"}}/>}
        <Button1 onClick={clickMe}>{decline}</Button1>
      </div>
     
            </div>
            <div className="timeContainer">
            <span className="time">{time}</span>
            </div>
             
           
            
            
            
             
           
              
            </div>
        </StyledNotificationPreview>
  
           
           

          
    
    )
}

export default NotificationPreview
```

In this file I have imported notification preview from the components folder and want to display the button only for buzz you.
Index.jsx

```
import styles from '../../../styles/Notification.module.css'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Nav from '../../../components/Nav'
import {BodyLayout}  from '../../../components/BodyLayout';
import { NotificationLeftSidebar } from '../../../components/Notification/NotificationLeftSidebar'
import {NotificationPreview} from '../../../components/Notification/NotificationPreview'

const notifications = ({notification}) => {
 
  

    return (
      <>
      <Nav  />
      <BodyLayout height="90%">
          <div className={styles.leftSidebarContainer}>
            <NotificationLeftSidebar name="Notifications" logo={notification?.data?.icon || "/"}  description="You can find all the recent notifications that you have received in this space. Also you can use the settings section given below to control your application notifications."/>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.notificationPage}>
            <div className={styles.notificationContainer}>
             <NotificationPreview    avatar="https://images.pexels.com/photos/220453/pexels-photo-220453.jpeg"
             para="viewed your profile" time="45 sec ago" name="Alex Edwards"
             />
             <NotificationPreview    avatar="https://images.pexels.com/photos/415829/pexels-photo-415829.jpeg"
             para="joined in a new Think Tank - " time="20 min ago" name="Yvonne Thompson" stream="Engineering"
             />
             <NotificationPreview    avatar="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1043471/pexels-photo-1043471.jpeg"
             para="has buzzed you" time="Yesterday" name="Dominik Doudny" accept="Accept" decline="Decline"
             />
             <NotificationPreview    avatar="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1382731/pexels-photo-1382731.jpeg"
             para="has commented on your post" time="Last week" name="Leanne Simpson "
             

             />
             <NotificationPreview    avatar="https://images.pexels.com/photos/678783/pexels-photo-678783.jpeg"
             para="has liked your post" time="Last week" name="Mónica Ribeiro"
             />
             <NotificationPreview    avatar="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3779760/pexels-photo-3779760.jpeg"
             para="has added a new post in " time="6 months ago" name="Jurrien Oldhof"
             stream="Think Tank - Computer Science"
             />
            </div>
            
          </div>

         
        </BodyLayout>
      </>
    )
}

export default notifications
```

Comment: can you explain more. I find you question confusing

Comment: I want the button to show only when its buzzed which is shown in index.jsx which has notification preview tag but not for other notificationpreview tag which has other para like viewed your profile.